# How to Sync Notes & Highlights from Kindle Account to iOS / Android Apps - Similar to what ReadWise does

Tags: android, ios, web-scraping, kindle

I've been researching for ways in which I could fetch Notes & Highlights from my Kindle Account to an iOS/Android App.

**Things I know so far**

1. There is no official Kindle API which Amazon provides, at the moment (Sep 2021)
2. There are few ways in which I could achieve this functionality but most of them are from Web-**Scraping** in which I would have to explicitly provide email address and password for the Amazon account for accessing highlights from [Kindle Highlights Url](https://read.amazon.com/notebook)
3. There are few git projects which already help with web-**scraping** but again, we have to explicitly provide email address and password

- PHP : https://github.com/johnpaulhayes/Kindle-Highlights
- Ruby : https://github.com/kyamaguchi/kindle_manager
- Ruby : https://github.com/speric/kindle-highlights

4. There are few official app which have this functionality of syncing all the highlights from Kindle to the app but I'm not sure how they achieve this

- ReadWise : https://readwise.io
- Calibre : https://calibre-ebook.com
- clippings.io : https://www.clippings.io

So just to summarise my question.
I'm looking for a way to access Kindle Highlights & Notes from my kindle account directly to my app both in iOS and Android. 
From the examples above, I know its possible but not sure how to go about implementing it. 
 Any help would be appreciated